# Running docker containe process as non root user

Tags: docker, dockerfile

What is the best way to running process in docker container as non root user. Adding a user in host and docker group or by creating a user and group as part of Dockerfile

Comment: A container can't see the host's `/etc/passwd` file, which pretty much requires it to add its own non-default user in its image's `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Can you explain more on the requirement? One way through which you can set the user with which command should run is via `--user <name>` option to `docker run` command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the best way to running process in docker container as non root user.

Is by creating a non privileged user in the dockerfile, that have an user id greater or equal to `1000`, and ensuring that is the default user when starting the docker container.

> Adding a user in host and docker group

The host machine doesn't share user or groups with a docker container, only shares the Kernel.

> or by creating a user and group as part of Dockerfile

Yes this is the correct approach as I already mentioned.

## Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:9

RUN apt update && \
    apt upgrade -y && \

    # Adjust the user id 1000 to match the user id in your Linux host
    useradd -m -u 1000 -s /usr/bin/bash stackoverflow

# Ensures that the docker container always start with this user, unless we 
# explicit override it with docker run --user username ....
USER stackoverflow

# The default dir when starting the docker container. 
WORKDIR /home/stackoverflow

CMD bash
```

Build it:

```
sudo docker build --tag stackoverflow .
```

## Docker Container

Let's create first a file in the host to map into the docker container:

```
╭─exadra37@laptop ~/Developer/StackOverflow/57331317  
╰─➤  printf "\nHost user:  $(id -un) with id: $(id -u)\n" > usernames.txt

╭─exadra37@laptop ~/Developer/StackOverflow/57331317  
╰─➤  ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 exadra37 exadra37 4096 Aug  3 09:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 exadra37 exadra37 4096 Aug  2 18:59 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 exadra37 exadra37  173 Aug  2 19:18 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 exadra37 exadra37   82 Aug  3 09:59 usernames.txt

╭─exadra37@laptop ~/Developer/StackOverflow/57331317  
╰─➤  cat usernames.txt 

Host user:  exadra37 with id: 1000
```

Running the docker container with the file we just created in the host:

```
╭─exadra37@laptop ~/Developer/StackOverflow/57331317  
╰─➤  sudo docker run --rm -v $PWD/usernames.txt:/home/stackoverflow/usernames.txt -it stackoverflow bash
```

Now we  are inside the docker container:

```
stackoverflow@367236be38d1:~$ ls -al
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 1 stackoverflow stackoverflow 4096 Aug  3 08:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root          root          4096 Aug  2 18:19 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 stackoverflow stackoverflow  220 May 15  2017 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 stackoverflow stackoverflow 3526 May 15  2017 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 stackoverflow stackoverflow  675 May 15  2017 .profile
-rw-r--r-- 1 stackoverflow stackoverflow   36 Aug  3 08:58 usernames.txt

stackoverflow@367236be38d1:~$ cat usernames.txt 


Host user:  exadra37 with id: 1000
```

As we can see above the we can read the file we created in the host, and we can even save to it:

```
stackoverflow@367236be38d1:~$ printf "\nContainer user:  $(id -un) with id: $(id -u)\n" >> usernames.txt
```

Lets' read the file again:

```
stackoverflow@367236be38d1:~$ cat usernames.txt 

Host user:  exadra37 with id: 1000

Container user:  stackoverflow with id: 1000
```

As we can see the file contains another line, and we can see that despite the usernames being different the user id is the same for both the host and container user, and this is what allows us to not have permissions issues between the host and the container.

Lets's confirm manually the usernames and id's in the container:

```
stackoverflow@367236be38d1:~$ id -u
1000

stackoverflow@367236be38d1:~$ id -un
stackoverflow
```

and now in the host:

```
stackoverflow@367236be38d1:~$ exit
exit

╭─exadra37@laptop ~/Developer/StackOverflow/57331317  
╰─➤  id -u
1000

╭─exadra37@laptop ~/Developer/StackOverflow/57331317  
╰─➤  id -un
exadra37
```

As we can see they are the same as we saved into the file, and once more you can see the same user id between the host and the docker container, despite usernames being different. For linux what matters is the user id, the username is just to help us humans.

Before we finish lets make sure that the file in the host reflects the changes we made to it in the docker container:

```
╭─exadra37@laptop ~/Developer/StackOverflow/57331317  
╰─➤  cat usernames.txt 

Host user:  exadra37 with id: 1000

Container user:  stackoverflow with id: 1000

╭─exadra37@laptop ~/Developer/StackOverflow/57331317  
╰─➤
```

Comment: Thanks!! Actually we already have a set of docker file where we are creating a non privileged user in Dockerfile. But now it has been decided to change all our base images to  redhat/ubi/minimal image. The Redhat minimal image does not have package to add user. Looks like I need to add required package to add user in container. But if this is the best way of adding user I was thinking why it is not included in Redhat minimal image.

Comment: Developers do stuff by convenience and unfortunately, more often than not, security is an after though... In docker I see them more concerned with the size then with the security, and if this base image does not have a non root user by default, its just a bad start in terms of security, but after all their main goal may be the image size, not to have a base secure image :(

Comment: @Exadra37 Why the non privileged user in the dockerfile, should have an user id greater or equal to 1000? and why it should matches with the user id in the Linux host?

Comment: In Linux any Id below 1000 is reserved for system use, services and other special accounts, for example the `root` user is `0`.  Regular users UIDs are assigned from 1000, and represent user without system privileges, aka the ones that need `sudo` access. The reason why it needs to match it's explained in my answer: `and we can see that despite the usernames being different the user id is the same for both the host and container user, and this is what allows us to not have permissions issues between the host and the container.`